# PC does not boot after upgrade to Windows 10, BIOS inaccessible

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded a Windows 8 PC to Windows 10. After the upgrade, I was notified that the update has failed, so I let the system restore the old state.

However, when I came back to check the PC, it was turned off. When I turned it on, it sounded as if the PC runs normally, but there was no output on the PC screen. Not even the manufacturer's logo that usually appears at the very first. I tried to access the BIOS several times by pressing the respective button after boot, but there was no reaction. Bootable USB sticks with Live-Linux also were not recognized.

Do you have an idea what might be the issue here? I find it quite strange that a failed Windows update can go so bad that I cannot even access the BIOS anymore.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105519/discussion-on-question-by-green-pc-does-not-boot-after-upgrade-to-windows-10-bi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While having the issue, I observed the following symptoms: Keyboard shows no light, display gets no signal and turns into energy saving mode, fan is consistently running as fast as possible.

After some experimentation, I found that after removing the power cord and CMOS battery, the BIOS shows up exactly once. Every following restart would stuck before anything can be done. In the BIOS setup menu, I found that the BIOS version was A02 (the PC in question is from Dell), apparently a very old one, so I fetched the newest BIOS file from DELL's support site and installed this via the One-Time Boot Menu of the PC (Dell PCs usually open this when pressing F12 while the BIOS is active). Now, it works flawlessly!

So, to summarize, the two main actions are:

1. While in the faulty state, reset BIOS before every boot by removing any power source (battery, cable) from the board.
2. Update the BIOS to the newest version.

To update the BIOS, I downloaded the newest BIOS from Dell's support site and put this onto a FAT32 formatted USB stick. Next, I shutdown the machine, removed any energy source from the board for a few seconds, reboot and entered the one-time boot menu by pressing F12 while BIOS is active. There, I select the option to flash a BIOS and followed the instructions on screen.